# Textview alignment issue when changing font/text size

Tags: android, fonts, textview, alignment

I have looked through quite a few answers and questions here on stackoverflow but have not found anything really helpful regarding my problem.

I have two textviews of equal size and equal properties right next to each other, the xml layout is this (only textsize differ)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_content_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:text="201.5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems="62" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/data_content_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:ems="62"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="201.5"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and the code is this

package com.example.fonttest;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView textViewLeft  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_content_left);
    TextView textViewRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.data_content_right);

    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/wwDigital.ttf");

    textViewLeft.setTypeface(myTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
    textViewRight.setTypeface(myTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Why is the height of the 'white space' below the numbers changing with text/font size? (se image below)

How can I determine if the problem has something to do with the font or with the textview?

I'm using this font: [http://www.dafont.com/ww-digital.font][3]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the same font ie **ttf** for both text view and use android:ems in Textview to define max and min value of it.

Comment: Thanks! I have not seen the android:ems property before. I have tried to specify android:ems on the textview in question but it does not change anything. Still the vertical white space changes with changing textsize...

Comment: I have now edited the question so that the included xml and code gives the output shown in the image. I hope the spec is clear now.

Comment: In the graphical layout the problem persists with the font used there so I think the issue not font related (or not only font related).

Comment: it the problem with font your are using ........if your think font is not the issue then download any other android compatible font and use it instead .

Comment: look here ["http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Font.html"]

Comment: @user2007354 I'm not sure the problem is due to the font only. The problem persists with the default font as well.

Comment: @Vipin Sahu: The renderscript is new to me. The documentation says that the renderscript Font class is deprecated. Also I'm not sure how the renderscript can deal with this problem...

Comment: In short time you can set the margin to your another textview so that it look similar in alignment with the other one and post the bug to code.google.com .....